# Remove specific row in csv file without create new file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file like that :

```
firstname;lastname
John;Stones
Remi;Jack
```

I want to remove row that begin by "Remi" without create an other file and put the data in.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how about override the same file?

Comment: Open an editor - wordpad, vim, emacs, or any other that come to mind.  Delete the line.  Save the file.  Aside from that, 2 things: 1) People can't help you without either a lot more information (the path to the file, for one thing), or some sample code of what you've already got.  2) At best, you'll be overwriting the existing file, and when you're doing that in a program, the safest thing is to write it to a temporary file and then copy that file on top of the original.  This may or may not fit your "without create new file" rule.  As I mentioned at the start - just edit the file yourself.

Comment: Override the row that begin by "Remi" on the same file.

Comment: @JackR if you use `vim` then you can read http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_CSV_files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, loading the file and then just filter what you want:

```
with open(filepath, "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    data = filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("Remi"), data)
with open(filepath, "w") as f:
    for l in data:
        f.write(l)
```

Comment: yep, quick responses make this happen, thanks @ScottMermelstein

Comment: That's why quick responses shouldn't happen.  Don't worry about being the fastest gun in the west.  Be the best answer, and the votes will come over time.  (Not to mention, this question is sufficiently bad that it probably shouldn't be answered anyway.)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein, wasnt trying to be quickest, just kindda busy at the moment , thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy in [vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor))

`g/^Remi/d`

`g`- go for all line.
`^Remi` starting with "Remi"
`d` delete those.

This work for me